# Getting Bulk API details from my.salesforce.com organization

Tags: api, bulk-api

I am trying to query a BULK API Job for its status. My organization's URL ends in my.salesforce.com (e.g. https://.my.salesforce.com) but I cannot figure our the correct URL to get the job status.

I was successful with this previously with a non-branded Salesforce instance (e.g. http://na34.salesforce.com) following details here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_jobs_get_details.htm

Previously I queried https://na34—api.salesforce.com/services/async/APIversion/job/jobId and would get results just fine.

What is the correct path to query for my.salesforce.com Organizations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should be getting the domain for your API calls from the process where you establish an API session. E.g. when you use the SOAP API login calls it will send back a serverURL. If you use this as the basis of subsequent API calls you shouldn't have a problem. Same with if you used OAuth and the access token.

Is it possible that your org was split from one pod/instance to another recently? You may find that you are no longer on na34.

With My Domain enabled it should be possible to use both the `na34.salesforce.com` and `mycustomdomain.my.salesforce.com` domains as API endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel,

So from what you are suggesting, I should be able to query https://examplecompany.my-api.salesforce.com/services/async/24.0/job/750A00000030Rdg to get the status of the job? Note the placement of the "-api", is this correct?

Comment: Many releases ago Salesforce stopped requiring the "-api" suffix on the subdomain for pods/instances. E.g. Where you used to have `na5-api.salesforce.com` you should now use `na5.salesforce.com`. I'm not sure how this translates to custom domains. I'd suggest going with whatever the SOAP API or OAuth return when logging in. This will be more flexible if they change it again in the future.