# bulk api from postman is not working for me

Tags: bulk-api, accesstoken

I'm sure it's a minor thing I miss over here, but I'm trying to solve it for like 2 hours without luck.

I'm trying to access the bulk API.

When I'm doing it with workbench its works fine :

```
/services/async/50.0/job
```

But when I try to do it from postman, Its throw me a status of : **400 no host.** with the next body :

```
<h1>Bad Message 400</h1>
<pre>reason: No Host</pre>
```

I believe it's because of the instance URL but I cant find what I'm doing wrong.

This is the requested URL:

```
https://instance.my.salesforce.com/services/async/50.0/job
```

I also tried the request URL from the docs :

```
https://instance_name—api.salesforce.com/services/async/APIversion/job
```

But when I'm adding the "-api" to the instance name - I'm getting the error from postman :

```
 Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND instance-api.my.salesforce.com
```

I put al the requested headers and body :

**Headers :**

Content-Type - application/json

Accept - application/json

X-SFDC-Session - access token

**body :**

```
{"operation":"upsert","object":"Account","contentType":"JSON","externalIdFieldName":"externalField__c"}
```

BTW -

I saw this question: [Getting Bulk API details from my.salesforce.com organization](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101704/getting-bulk-api-details-from-my-salesforce-com-organization)

and I made sure I'm on the right URL - when getting the access token from salesforce (I looked o the returned instance_url )

many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally unchecked some headers that Postman inserted automatically:

```
Content-Length : <calculated when request is sent>

Host: <calculated when request is sent>
```

When I checked them its worked.

Thanks.